# How to use log4 and logback together?

Tags: logging, log4j, logback, slf4j

In my project I use customer libraries. Inside these libraries use `log4j`.

I like logback. Is it possible to use `slf4j` in my project at this case?

I want to use all features of logback, especially dynamic configuration update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean those libraries you use have explicit calls to log4j Loggers.

In that case, using slf4j + logback as your logging implementation *and including the log4j calls* is quite simple.

As the slf4j documentation says, you just have to replace all the log4j dependencies with a single one from slf4j, named log4j-over-slf4j: http://slf4j.org/legacy.html#log4j-over-slf4j.

In case you are using maven the correct dependency is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Any code that is under your direct control can just use slf4j + logback as it always would.

Comment: Thus we use following scheme ?  http://dl1.joxi.net/drive/2016/09/07/0005/3037/338909/09/3b24dbd70c.jpg

Comment: Exactly. These bridge dependencies all make sure calls to legacy APIs like Log4J are forwarded to slf4j. From there you can do with them as you please, i. e. use the logging implementation of your choice: logback.